# independent searches on GPU -- how to synchronize its finish?

Tags: multithreading, synchronization, opencl, gpgpu, gpu

Assume I have some algorithm generateRandomNumbersAndTestThem() which returns true with probability p and false with probability 1-p. Typically p is very small, e.g. p=0.000001.

I'm trying to build a program in JOCL that estimates p as follows: generateRandomNumbersAndTestThem() is executed in parallel on all available shader cores (preferrably of multiple GPUs), until at least 100 trues are found. Then the estimate for p is 100/n, where n is the total number of times that generateRandomNumbersAndTestThem() was executed.

For p = 0.0000001, this means roughly 10^9 independent attempts, which should make it obvious why I'm looking to do this on GPUs. But I'm struggling a bit how to implement the stop condition properly. My idea was to have something along these lines as the kernel:

```
__kernel void sampleKernel(all_the_input, __global unsigned long *totAttempts) {
    int gid = get_global_id(0);
    //here code that localizes all_the_input for faster access
    while (lessThan100truesFound) {
        totAttempts[gid]++;
        if (generateRandomNumbersAndTestThem()) 
            reportTrue();
    }
}
```

How should I implement this without severe performance loss, given that

- triggering of the "if" will be a very rare event and so it is not a problem if all threads have to wait while reportTrue() is executed
- lessThan100truesFound has to be modified only once (from true to false) when reportTrue() is called for the 100th time (so I don't even know if a boolean is the right way)
- the plan is to buy brand-new GPU hardware for this, so you can assume a recent GPU, e.g. multiple ATI Radeon HD7970s. But it would be nice if I could test it on my current HD5450.

I assume that something can be done similar to Java's "synchronized" modifier, but I fail to find the exact way to do it. What is the "right" way to do this, i.e. any way that works without severe performance loss?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'd suggest not using global flag to stop kernel, but rather run kernel to do certain amount of attempts, check on host if you have accumulated enough 'successes', and repeat if necessary. Using cycle of undefined length in kernel is bad since GPU driver could be killed by watch-dog timer. Besides, checking some global variable at each iteration would certainly screw kernel performance.

This way, `reportTrue` could be implemented as `atomic_inc` to some counter residing in global memory.

```
__kernel void sampleKernel(all_the_input, __global unsigned long *successes) {
    int gid = get_global_id(0);
    //here code that localizes all_the_input for faster access
    for (int i = 0; i < ATT_PER_THREAD; ++i) {
        if (generateRandomNumbersAndTestThem()) 
            atomic_inc(successes);
    }
}
```

ATT_PER_THREAD is to be adjusted depending on how long it takes to execute `generateRandomNumbersAndTestThem()`. Kernel launch overhead is pretty small, so there usually is no need to make your kernel run more than 0.1--1 second

Comment: The problem with this strategy is that there's a fair amount of memory to be localized. The input consists mainly of a graph, and certain flows have to be computed along the edges of the graph. The total amount of memory to be transferred could easily be 1 MB or more, doing this constantly for each kernel sounds like a major bottleneck to me. Would a global flag to stop kernel have a major cost, given that I have to perform thousands of local memory operations in generateRandomNumbersAndTestThem()?

Comment: So, in short, kernel launch overhead may be pretty small, but memory localization probably isn't. Technically it should be avoidable since the graph remains constant all the time, but I have no idea how to implement this. Is it possible to use your method without having to re-localize the same memory content every kernel launch again?

Comment: 1MB is not that much, however it heavily depends on access pattern and memory type. Given that you haven't provided much inforation about `generateRandomNumbersAndTestThem()` it's impossible to claim something for sure, but as a general rule of GPGPU programming, any interthread synchronization should be avoided (except for barriers on local memory access).

Comment: This should give you an idea of generateRandomNumbersAndTestThem(): http://pastebin.com/pDJ4hbg6 it is a java version of what I want to implement. The bottleneck comes from iterating over all the edges of a bipartite graph, which I do by storing for each edge it's vertices of both bipartition classes (edgeRow and edgeColumn). A large example would have lengte=hoogte=2000 and aantalEnen=100000, a small example would have lengte=hoogte=500 and aantalEnen=2000. I also use two binary matrices G, H of size (lengte x hoogte). The rest is not really relevant I think.